# Regex to validate if string is valid SQL column name

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am searching a regex to validate if a string could be a valid SQL column name.

I would like to use PCRE syntax.

Up to now I found this:

```
[\w-]+
```

But I think this is not enough. I have seen the `/` too (in SAP).

AFAIK the spec is closed source (you need to pay for it).

From the docs [(Python re)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html):

> \w
>       Matches Unicode word characters; this includes most characters that can be part of a word in any language, as well as numbers and the
>   underscore. If the ASCII flag is used, only [a-zA-Z0-9_] is matched.

How does the regex look like to validate SQL column names?

The string should be able to used like this `my_column`.

AFAIK reserved words are valid, since you can use them like this:

```
select * from my_table where "where" = 'here'
```

"where" is the name of a column. The regex does not need to care for reserved words.

Comment: What do you mean "validate SQL column names"?  Almost any string can be a column name if it is escaped.

Comment: And many "valid" strings need escaping anyway if they are [reserved words](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-keywords-appendix.html).

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter I updated the question (concerning reserved words).

Comment: Do you mean valid in standard SQL or valid in PostgreSQL?

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter: yes of course.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I mean " valid in standard SQL"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we follow the PostgreSQL documentation:

> SQL identifiers and key words must begin with a letter (`a`-`z`, but also letters with diacritical marks and non-Latin letters) or an underscore (`_`). Subsequent characters in an identifier or key word can be letters, underscores, digits (`0`-`9`), or dollar signs (`$`). Note that dollar signs are not allowed in identifiers according to the letter of the SQL standard [...]

we could write a regular expression for identifiers like this:

```
^([[:alpha:]_][[:alnum:]_]*|("[^"]*")+)$
```

The second branch of the regular expression takes care of quoted identifiers.

Answer (score 3):

The [manual clarifies](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS):

> SQL identifiers and key words must begin with a letter (`a`-`z`, but also
>   letters with diacritical marks and non-Latin letters) or an underscore
>   (`_`). Subsequent characters in an identifier or key word can be
>   letters, underscores, digits (`0-9`), or dollar signs (`$`). Note that
>   dollar signs are not allowed in identifiers according to the letter of
>   the SQL standard, so their use might render applications less
>   portable. The SQL standard will not define a key word that contains
>   digits or starts or ends with an underscore, so identifiers of this
>   form are safe against possible conflict with future extensions of the
>   standard.
>
> The system uses no more than `NAMEDATALEN`-1 bytes of an identifier;
>   longer names can be written in commands, but they will be truncated.
>   By default, `NAMEDATALEN` is 64 so the maximum identifier length is 63
>   bytes. If this limit is problematic, it can be raised by changing the
>   `NAMEDATALEN` constant in `src/include/pg_config_manual.h`.

And:

> There is a second kind of identifier: the delimited identifier or
>   quoted identifier. It is formed by enclosing an arbitrary sequence of
>   characters in double-quotes (`"`). [...]
>
> Quoted identifiers can contain any character, except the character
>   with code zero. (To include a double quote, write two double quotes.)
>   This allows constructing table or column names that would otherwise
>   not be possible, such as ones containing spaces or ampersands. The
>   length limitation still applies.

There is more, you can even use escaped unicode characters like: `U&"d\0061t\+000061"`. Read the whole chapter.

So *any character, except the character with code zero* is allowed in a valid identifier, once the name is double-quoted. And without double-quotes, even simple strings like 'select' may be invalid if they happen to be [reserved words](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-keywords-appendix.html). (The concept of reserved words is an unfortunate one, set by the SQL standard, hard to change now.)

You might just let Postgres do the work, using [`quote_ident()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER):

```
SELECT quote_ident('0of') = '0of';
```

> Quotes are added only if necessary.

The expression returns `true` for valid identifiers. Or just used the result of `quote_ident('$identifier')` to get a legal name in either case (quoted if necessary).